# Mathematical Construction: ADM Formulation in General Relativity

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, general-relativity

I'm doing my undergraduated thesis and now I'm looking for references that presents ADM Formulation in General Relativity mathematically.

I studied the basic of General Relativity theory by [O'Neill Semi-Riemannian Geometry](https://www.amazon.com.br/Semi-Riemannian-Geometry-Applications-Relativity-103/dp/0125267401) and I would like references (papers, monographs, books, lecture notes etc...) like this one.

By the way, if anyone knows similar references that presents Palatini Formulation of General Relativity, I'd be grateful!

Comment: I'm doing a GR thesis, too. It is really hard for me. By the way, you may want to try *General Relativity* by Robert M. Wald. This book is quite a piece, though, not easy to read.